# How can I check if session values is there using file_get_contents in PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to check if session is there or not using file_get_contents in localhost.

And my code

```
<?php
echo $datas=file_get_contents(getStoreURL($storeid).'admin/tracker.php?getSession=1');
?>
```

and

tracker.php

```
if($_REQUEST['getSession'])
{   

    if($_SESSION['admin'])
    {
        $sessionVal=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $sessionVal=0;
    }
    echo $sessionVal;
}
?>
```

How to I check if session is there or not?

Comment: it depends on how do you store session values i.e in tmp folder or in database. based on that you can check session values.

Comment: why not `include` or `require` the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

> file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string

The key word here is ***string***.

A *very* **dangerous** approach would be to `eval` the `$datas` variable, however it's not advised.

```
$datas=file_get_contents(getStoreURL($storeid).'admin/tracker.php?getSession=1');
eval($datas);
```

I would `include` or `require` the file within your router / brain file, or even just merge the contents of `tracker.php` in the file that is using `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't understand your question.
Why don't you use isset() for example to check if a session exists and then include the file you need?

From PHP Manual:
If `$_SESSION` (or `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is used, use `isset()` to check a variable is registered in `$_SESSION`.

Or you can use a combined version:

```
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    // session isn't started
    session_start();
}
```